# How to manage foreground window across processes?

Tags: delphi, window, ipc, delphi-2007, foreground

I have two projects which run as separate processes, but belong to the same application:

- Master (contains `TMasterMainForm` and `TMasterModalForm`)
- Slave (contains `TSlaveForm`)

The typical way to use this application is like this:

1. Master is started and shows the `TMasterMainForm`.
2. The user can run the slave by clicking a button in `TMasterMainForm`.
3. Master starts the Slave process.
4. Slave shows the `TSlaveForm`.
5. Master sends the `TForm.Handle` of `TMasterMainForm` to Slave. (via IPC = WM_COPYDATA)

Step 5 is done so that when Slave is closing it can set the foreground window back to `TMasterMainForm`. This is done to improve the user experience.

This worked fine until we introduced `TMasterModalForm`.

`TMasterModalForm` can be started using another button in `TMasterMainForm`. It is a separate window, but is shown modal and has the `TMasterMainForm` as its explicit popup parent.

Now when the `TSlaveForm` is closed the Slave application calls `SetForegroundWindow` on the handle of the `TMasterMainForm`, but this is not correct anymore since there is a modal form (`TMasterModalForm`) on top of it.

So the question is:

How do I manage setting the foreground window in this non trivial situation?

PS: This is a simplified description, the real application is also doing this foreground window stuff the other way around.

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow(GetLastActivePopup(MasterMainFormHandle))`?

Comment: @Sertac Surely `Application.BringToFront` would be more natural?

Comment: @David - No, that's supposed to be called from the 'slave'. Jens would change only one line of his code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set the foreground window to the master main form because it is disabled. It is disabled because you are showing a modal form whose owner is that main form.

The obvious solution is to set the foreground window to be the modal form rather than the main form. Since your slave app presumably cannot easily know which window is active, you should re-work your IPC to allow the slave app to ask the master app which window is active, and then make that the foreground window.

A more elegant solution would be to let the master app call `SetForegroundWindow`. In fact it would probably be simpler just to call `Application.BringToFront` from the master process. Of course, the slave process would still need to send a message to the master in order to invoke this. The final piece in the puzzle is dealing with the focus-stealing restrictions but you can do that using [`AllowSetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668.aspx). You need your slave process to call this passing the ID of the master process.

Comment: I'll go with the more elegant solution then :).

Comment: Unfortunatly the `AllowSetForegroundWindow` call doesn't seem to work. The Master application is not brought to the foreground, instead the taskbar icon just flashes.

Comment: I'm quite sure it does work. I can't diagnose what's wrong though.

Comment: When are you calling `AllowSetForegroundWindow`? Are you doing it just before you send the message to the master program? You know you have to do it every single time you send that message.

Comment: I do it everytime and just before I send the message. `AllowSetForegroundWindow` returns `False` and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, I double checked the process id.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Works perfectly for me. The PID must be wrong. It's the only parameter!

Comment: I have made this into a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399023/how-to-use-allowsetforegroundwindow

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, I would not call SetForegroundWindow from the slave application, but instead send a custom activate message to the master application. In this message you can pass the desired handle in WParam or LParam. The master application itself can determine whether it can activate that handle, or need to activate the modal form instead. You put the responsibility of activating the right window in the application itself.

PS: You don't need WM_COPYDATA to send a handle. You can just pass in in WParam or LParam of any message you make up. This goes for the handle to send back as I explained above, but also for the handle that is sent to the slave in the first place.

Comment: The master application can't call SetForegroundWindow when it doesn't "own" the currently active window, see the Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, David gave the missing piece of the puzzle, `AllowSetForegroundWindow`, I should have noticed that before ...