# How to use AllowSetForegroundWindow?

Tags: delphi, winapi, window

I have two windows in separate applications. The first application has a button that starts the second application with its window handle and process id:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WinExec(PChar('Second.exe ' + IntToStr(Handle) + ' ' + IntToStr(GetCurrentProcessId)), SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
end;
```

The second application also has a button which should set the foreground window to the first application:

```
function AllowSetForegroundWindow(AHandle: HWND): Boolean; external 'user32.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not AllowSetForegroundWindow(StrToInt(ParamStr(2))) then begin
    ShowMessage('ERROR');
    Exit;
  end;
  SendMessage(StrToInt(ParamStr(1)), WM_APP + 1, 0, 0);
end;
```

The first application has a message handler that handles `WM_APP + 1` like this:

```
procedure TForm1.WWAppPlusOne(var Msg: TMsg);
begin
  Application.BringToFront;
end;
```

When I start the first application and press on the button, the second application starts. When I press the button on the second application it shows `ERROR`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: WinExec has been deprecated for over 15 years. Isn't it time we all stopped using it in new code?

Comment: @RobKennedy I don't use it in production code, this was just a quick and dirty example where I didn't want to write all the `CreateProcess` stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your declaration of `AllowSetForegroundWindow` is incorrect. You have omitted the calling convention. The data types you have used are wrong too, although that's probably benign for you at the moment.

It should look like this:

```
function AllowSetForegroundWindow(dwProcessId: DWORD): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'user32.dll';
```